# What is "virtualapp/didlogical"?

Tags: credentials

I was rooting around in my credential manager and found a credential for "virtualapp/didlogical". I didn't put it there, I don't recognize it and I am finding conflicting info about it. It may be a keylogger, or used by Windows Live or Google Talk or any of a number of other programs, depending on who you believe. Can anyone tell me what this is?
It seems to be created by Windows 7 and Windows 8. Some say that it is used by virtualization features included in Windows and by Windows Live Essentials products.

Comment: the username of the vitualapp/didlogical on mine was: 8n3ggzfckho Something is suspicious.

Comment: @André a search in Google does indicate that it is a credential made by Windows Live products, although no formal reasoning was made: a Microsoft employee just came in and said that. I think that accounts for something. Here is the relevant [technet post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bb411d90-3efb-41de-a601-f3b97944fdb5/windows-credentials-where-to-get-more-details?forum=w7itprosecurity)

Answer (score 35):

There are quite a few threads on answers.microsoft.com where Microsoft engineers
confirm that this is indeed a credential created by Microsoft products:

[**Unknown generic credentials in windows 7 - virtualapp/didlogical**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/unknown-generic-credentials-in-windows-7/eb730de0-bf64-4a26-992f-330566a76600)
A Microsoft employee called Divya R says:

> Virtualapp/Didlogical is a credential that is stored when you use any
> of the Windows Live products, this can include Windows Live Messenger,
> Windows Live Mail, Windows Live Sign-In Assisstant, Windows XP Mode
> and other Microsoft services.
>
> You may delete the entry from the Credential Manager.

[**how did virtualapp/didlogical arrive in my windows 8 generic credentials on my desktop computer and does it affect internet access?**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/how-did-virtualappdidlogical-arrive-in-my-windows/2d0d4b61-2b82-43fb-8049-8f97e16fd348)
A Microsoft employee called Tadasha Mishra says:

> The entry Virtualapp/Didlogical is a credential that is created when
> you use any of the Windows Live applications and other Microsoft
> services.

[**Under Generic Credentials I am getting VIRTUALAPP/DIDLOGICAL (but in lower case letters) I delete but it returns later. How do, I get rid of it permanantly?**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_scanning/under-generic-credentials-i-am-getting/c9df342b-d345-4caa-9a3b-f6d2992d4c1f)
A Microsoft employee called Winston M says:

> Virtualapp/Didlogical is a credential that is stored when you use any
> of the Windows Live products, this can include Windows Live Messenger,
> Windows Live Mail, Windows Live Sign-In Assisstant, Windows XP Mode
> and other Microsoft services.
>
> You may delete the entry from the Credential Manager.

---

There are also cases where Microsoft products malfunctioned because this credential
was incorrect.

For example, in [OneNote 2010 not syncing with SkyDrive Fix](http://burianek.com/blog/archives/category/tech) :

> Since the recent IE fix I’ve had an issue with OneNote 2010 not
> syncing with OneDrive (formally SkyDrive). It would say I needed a
> password to connect and when I would try to sign in it would come back
> with: “We can’t sign you in because the network isn’t available. Make
> sure your computer is connected to the Internet and try again.”
>
> Since the failure occurred when trying to sign into Windows Live,
> decided it might be an issue with the Windows Live ID credential store
> by Windows – turns out I was right. By deleting the stored credentials
> I was able to get OneNote syncing again.

---

A good summary of this subject can be found in the article
[What is Virtualapp/Didlogical?](http://windows7themes.net/en-us/what-is-virtualappdidlogical/) :

> Virtualapp/Didlogical is a credential that is stored when you use any
> of the Windows Live products, this can include Windows Live Messenger,
> Windows Live Mail, Windows Live Sign-In Assisstant, Windows XP Mode
> and other Microsoft services.
>
> In general it is safe to delete it – however, it’s pretty useless to
> remove it IF you are using Windows Live or any other Microsoft
> services on a regular basis. I would therefore not recommend to delete
> it.
>
> If you continue to use the Microsoft Windows Live products, you will
> always have this entry. The only solutions is to uninstall Windows
> Live products and look for alternatives, but since this is not a
> security problem there is absolutely no reason to do that.

Answer (score 5):

According to someone at Channel9:

> Official answer: Yes. This credential is created by and used by Wndows[sic] Live.

See [this thread](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Can-someone-at-Microsoft-confirm-whether-the-virtualappdidlogical-entry-in-the-Credential-Manager-wa). I have no idea whether the user in question is actually a microsoft employee though.